# PdfViewer library full screen

Tags: java, android

I'm using PdfViewer.jar library for opening the PDF files in my Application,
The problem is, i want to show my pdf in full screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This one you can try it which works properly.

https://github.com/bitfield66/PdfViewerAndroid_Offline